# OS X — Create keyboard shortcut programmatically

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have several OS X keyboard shortcuts, that I have to copy between machines. For most other things, e.g. dock contents, I have scripts to automate setup on a new mac. I'd like to do the same with keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a way to create keyboard shortcuts via the command line, or by editing a preferences file somewhere?

Comment: You should specify how you're creating the keyboard shortcuts on the original Mac.  The method of copying them will completely depend on where you're creating them (and where they are stored).

Comment: This? http://superuser.com/questions/436884/how-to-sync-custom-shortcuts-between-two-macs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sitting at a Mac right now, but have you looked in ***~/Library/KeyBindings/*** ?

Comment: I don't seem to have a Keybindings, in /Library or ~/Library.